# How to achive FK/PK relation between an Entity and View in Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, entity-framework

I have an Entity with a column that refers to a view. This entity column needs to act as a Foreign key and refer to a View. But the issue here is the View does not have a Primary key of its own so we cannot directly assign any unique id to be stored in Entity's column.
The view has 3 columns that are unique. Is there any way we can achieve such a FK PK relation between the entity and view with no PK.

Comment: Please show some relation ships on the tables. How does the entity refer to the view? That isn't really clear to me. Also this isn't really related to Spring Boot but is more of a JPA modelling question.

Comment: The entity actually needs just the first column as a FK PK relation from the view. Say the view has column 1, column 2 and column 3. The entity needs mapping about column 1 only. But the view has no PK of its own it just has a unique selection of these three columns i.e. it returns select distinct column1, column2 , column3. In this case how can we achieve FK PK in entity and what will actaully be stored in the database table of entity as view as no PK id. Could you please help?

Comment: Does it need to be a relation? If not why not just write a query that returns what you need. Not everything needs to be relationships. Next to that you can just specify which column is used for the join and the view can have a compound primary key for those 3 columns and you link with just one